# Email notification when login attempt fails on RDS SQL Server DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to get notified when there is an attempt to access our SQL database with the incorrect credentials. Is this something that I can do in AWS or do I need to do it in SQL Server?

I can manually look at the database log showing failed logins but no way of automating a check that would send a notification. I feel like i should be able to do this with cloudwatch alarms but cannot figure it out.

If it is possible to do in AWS I would appreciate any help. I have looked online and haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps feed the database logs to CloudWatch logs - it works for MySQL and PostgreSQL but not sure about SQL Server. If you can do that you can then set up CloudWatch triggers whenever the failed login event appears in the log and through CloudWatch alarm get a notification.